# How to make use of a cubemap in Blender Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I have a cubemap I got from somewhere that I want to use as a skybox for a scene, but it seems that there are no options in the World context to set it as the texture surrounding everything. "Image Texture" for Background color only gives me a single color across the scene that (I'm guessing) is the average of the colors in the texture, and "Environment Texture" doesn't allow for cube-based projection. How would I go about utilizing the texture I've gotten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just UV unwrap a Cube object, map the texture to the inside faces and then scale it up large enough to contain your scene. Should work just fine.